# Advice required in making a simple text editor using the Java Swing Class Library

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am a java beginner and I want to make a simple text editor but I find the following problem. The JTextArea doesn't re-size along with the JFrame. Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class textEditor
{
JFrame frame;
JTextArea textArea;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
//JButton button;

public textEditor()             //Constructor
{
    frame = new JFrame("Title of the frame!");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    textArea = new JTextArea("");
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    //button = new JButton();


}

public void launchFrame()
{
    //Adding Text Area and ScrollPane to the Frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    //Make the Close button to close the frame when clicked
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Displaying the Frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    textEditor window=new textEditor();
    window.launchFrame();
}
}
```

Please don't forget that I'm a beginner so please give me a solution in simple words.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JTextArea doesn't re-size along with the JFrame as you are using a `FlowLayout` manager which uses preferred sizes of components instead of expanding them to fill the full space of  the container. To fix you can remove the line:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

`JFrame` containers use `BorderLayout` manager by default, which will do the necessary sizing that you are looking for.

Also remove the line

```
frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
```

as only the `JScrollPane` is required to be added to the frame.

Comment: But, how can I make the scrollbar visible only when there is a need?

Comment: The default is for it/them to appear only when needed. The textarea needs to have text first.